# Cannot inject EntityManager declared in persistence.xml

Tags: java, jpa, persistence.xml, cdi-unit

I'm trying to develop a (Maven-based) jar library which can act as a DAL for my Java application.

This is my `persistence.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

   <persistence-unit name="DALPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:app/env/MyDataSource</jta-data-source>          
      <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the `DataSource` definition, done using the `@DataSourceDefinition` annotation

```
import javax.annotation.sql.DataSourceDefinition;
import javax.ejb.Startup;


@DataSourceDefinition(name = "java:app/env/MyDataSource",
                      className = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                      serverName="<serverIP>",
                      portNumber=3306,
                      user = "<username>",
                      password = "<pwd>",
                      databaseName = "<dbname>",
                      minPoolSize = 0,
                      initialPoolSize = 0
                      )
@Startup
public class MyDataSource {

}
```

This is the DAO which retrieves the `EntityManager` from the `persistence.xml` definition (I'm using [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) to simplify query definitions)

```
package my.dal.dao;
import my.domain.dal.QUser;
import my.domain.dal.User;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

import com.mysema.query.jpa.JPQLQuery;
import com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery;

@Default
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DALPersistenceUnit", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public User getMark()
    {
        QUser qUser = QUser.user;
        JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);          
        User mark = query.from(qUser).where(qUser.username.eq("mark")).uniqueResult(qUser);
        return mark;
    }       
}
```

Also, I added the `beans.xml` file in the `META-INF` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

This is the test class (I'm using [CDI-Unit](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/) for the CDI testing)

```
import my.dal.dao.UserDAO;
import my.domain.dal.User;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class DALUserTest {

    @Inject UserDAO userDAO;

    @Test
    public void testGetMark()
    {
        User user = userDAO.getMark(); // Here I get a NullPointerException
        assertTrue(user.getUsername()=="mark");
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get a NullPointerException at the marked line in the test class. Moreover, if I debug the test I can see that the `EntityManager entityManager` field of the `UserDAO` class is `null`, so it is not injected from the `persistence.xml` file.

Am I missing something in the Java persistence/CDI mechanism?

Thank you

EDIT 1: I have added Maven dependencies to

```
querydsl-core:3.3.2
querydsl-apt:3.3.2
querydsl-jpa:3.3.2
log4j:1.2.16
mysql-connector-java:5.1.29
hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.1.Final
hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final
cdi-unit:3.0.1
junit:4.11
javaee-api:7.0
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final
hibernate-core:4.3.1.Final
hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final
```

EDIT 2: Following @earthling advice, I added the following bean definition in the `beans.xm`l file

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DALPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
</bean>
```

But I get the following error in the `beans.xml` file

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'bean'. One of
>   '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":interceptors, "http:// 
>   java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":decorators,
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":alternatives}' is expected.

Answer (score 2):

You are configuring your datasource twice. In the persistence.xml and through  `@DataSourceDefinition`.

Since you are not running your tests inside an application server you need to [produce an EntityManager yourself](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Entity_Manager_Reference_Guide/ch02s04.html). A good Idea would be to use an EntityManagerProducer which can be switch with an alternative to run tests.

```
@RequestScoped
public class EntityManagerProvider {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

Then you need an Test-EntityManager Producer

```
@Alternative
@RequestScoped
public class EntityManagerProvider {


    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if(entityManager == null) {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("...");
            entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
        }
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

You can access your EntityManager this way
`@Inject private EntityManager em`

Comment: The jar library I'm developing will be integrated in a web application which will run on Wildfly (JBoss AS 8), so in the end the library will run in a application server. 

Do I need to write the EntityManagerProvider class even in this case?

Comment: This class is just to provide an EntityManager for your tests because they do not run on an application server.

Comment: Ok. I've added the code you provided but at the injection point I get this warning message "No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]". If I try to run the test it stops throwing this exception

http://pastebin.com/CnQmxj7Y

Comment: Did you active the alternative by adding it to the beans.xml?

More info to alternatives --> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html

Comment: Thank you, I added the alternative tag to the beans.xml. I'm sorry, but the problem persists :(

Comment: I added an return to the alternative EntityManagerProvider. Can you verfify that is class is working properly by calling getEntityManager and persisting something into the database?

Comment: Might I ask what the purpose is of tagging the producer as @RequestScoped ?

Comment: The Producer should work the same way as `@PersistenceContext`. Therefor it is requestscoped and gets an EntityManager injection on every request.

Comment: This is the code I wrote to test the EntityManager (without injection).

http://pastebin.com/j0jErMAc

And it works: it adds the provided User to the DB. So the problem seems to be that the project cannot find a bean to inject as stated in the third comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011055/cannot-inject-entitymanager-declared-in-persistence-xml/24013394?noredirect=1#comment37017949_24013394)

Comment: Try adding the alternative EntityManagerProvider like in the docs of cdi-uni:` @RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses(WarpDrive.class) // WarpDrive is available to use.
class TestStarship { `

Comment: I tried adding @AdditionalClasses({EntityManagerProvider.class}) but the problem still remains (http://pastebin.com/CnQmxj7Y). Moreover, I tried adding @ActivatedAlternatives(EntityManagerProvider.class) and got this exception http://pastebin.com/51cYKVk3

Comment: Now the test runs. I added `@AdditionalClasses(EntityManagerProvider.class)` and 
`@ActivatedAlternatives(EntityManagerProvider.class)` to the test class. Moreover I deleted the `@RequestScoped` annotation to the `EntityManagerProvider` class (as the exception was saying). My doubt now is: will an application (which includes the library I've written) inject the the `EntityManager` from the `persistence.xml` or will it use the `EntityManagerProvider` to build the `EntityManager`?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating entityManagerFactory in your bean xml and inject in to your DAO class via constructor injection

say

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
         <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DALPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:/<path-to>/persistence.xml" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You should create a default constructor for this.. or use setter injection and add setter method of entityManager..

Comment: The OP does not use Spring... check his Maven dependencies. `beans.xml` is for CDI.

Comment: So, should I use another EntityManagerFactory class? Which one?